# ¿Como puedo hacer para que Arduino lea los datos del script de Python?

Tags: python, arduino

Estoy haciendo un script en Python en el cual cambie el numero de la variable maximo_personas y ahora estoy haciendo para que desde arduino leea lo que le entra por python

El codigo que tengo es

```
import serial, time

arduino=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)

enviar=raw_input("Introduce un numero de aforo máximo")

arduino.write(str(enviar).encode())
arduino.write('\n'.encode())

ARDUINO

if (Serial.available()>0){
  int maximo_personas = 15;
  int enviado;

  enviado=Serial.parseInt();

  maximo_personas==enviado;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python**

Del lado de Python el script es más simple:

```
import serial

arduino=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)
enviar=input("Introduce un numero de aforo máximo ")
arduino.write(enviar.encode())
```

La función `input` me entrega una cadena unicode que incluye el ENTER al final. Sólo necesito aplicar `enconde()` antes de enviarla.

**Arduino**

Del lado Arduino vamos a usar el LED montado en la placa para chequear la recepción de datos: lo haremos parpadear `n / 2` veces, donde `n` es el valor enviado por Python:

```
int enviado; //Aqui enviamos el numero completo

void setup()
{
  //Inicializamos la comunicacion por Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  enviado = 0;
}

void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available() >= 1) {
    enviado = Serial.parseInt(); //Leer entero por serial
    Serial.read();  // Descartar ENTER al final del entero
  }
  if (enviado) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
    delay(250);
    enviado--;
  }
}
```

La precaución al usar `parseInt()` es que no lee el ENTER al final de número, por lo que tenemos que agregar un `Serial.read()` para deshacernos de ese caracter.

Como `enviado` es una variable global, conserva su valor en sucesivas iteraciones de `loop`.

En cada iteración se cambia el estado del LED sólo una vez. Este es el patrón de programación estándar en Arduino: cada pasada por `loop` debe ser tan corta como sea posible, a fin de dar tiempo para procesar otros eventos de la placa.